# How can I import a txt list from a dropbox link?

Tags: import

I have a large txt data stored in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkyoamgqop7kpio/data.txt?dl=0).

I have tried this:

```
dataa = ToExpression[
  Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkyoamgqop7kpio/data.txt?dl=0", 
   "JSON"]]
```

But it's not working.

How can I import this data?

Comment: `Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkyoamgqop7kpio/data.txt?dl=1", "TSV"]` works for me.  You can also use "Table" as the second argument.

Comment: @JasonB. yes, this works for me too. Could you please post your comment as an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here.  First, that Dropbox gives you a download link that goes to a web page, rather than serving the file directly:

```
StringTake[ Import[
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkyoamgqop7kpio/data.txt?dl=0", "Text"] , 200]
(* <!DOCTYPE html><html xml:lang="en" class="maestro" 
   xmlns="http://www.w4.org/1999/xhtml"><head><script 
   nonce="hZ8jZbVPCjAVTxp9v4nc">
   window._goch_ = {};
   window.addEventListener('click', function(event) *)
```

If you change the `0` at the end of the URL to a `1`, you get the file:

```
StringTake[
 Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkyoamgqop7kpio/data.txt?dl=1", 
  "Text"], 200]
(*
41.66666670000001   0.  -48.27198359004478
36.458333340625 0.  -52.44199291767245
31.249999987500004  0.  -55.61381644250923
26.041666640625003  0.  -57.787454164553765
20.833333300000003  0.  -58.9629060838065
*)
```

Next, there is the file format - the OP gives "JSON", but I don't think this is a valid JSON file, it looks more like a tab-separated-value file

```
Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkyoamgqop7kpio/data.txt?dl=\
1", "JSON"]

During evaluation of Import::jsonexpendofinput: Unexpected character found while looking for the end of input.

During evaluation of Import::jsonhintposandchar: An error occurred near character '0', at line 1:20
(* $Failed *)
```

So just use the "Table" import format:

```
Import[
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkyoamgqop7kpio/data.txt?dl=1", 
  "Table"] // Short
(* {{41.6667,0.,-48.272},<<19438>>,{37.1875,<<10>>,2193.48}} *)
```